# @font-face use for OTF fonts in node-webkit

Tags: node-webkit

webkitters:
I'm brand new to node-webkit and am very excited by the Chrome-level compliance with HTML5 and CSS3, 
as well as the benfits of node, itself.  I am experimenting with font usage in an ePub3 reading application
and have been able to easily embed .ttf, .woff and (even) .svg fonts by using the @font-face CSS3 mechanism.
Not so with .otf (and IE's .eot) fonts.  With the nw inspector, the elements show the proper font-family, the
font seems to load (no error messages in console) and the font resource shows up -- but the font does not appear.
The fallback system font shows, instead.  This is a concern, because the ePub3 specification for reading systems 
requires handling  TTF and OTF embedded fonts. Chrome, itself, has supported OTF fonts for some time, I believe.

(I am working on a Windows system.) Does anyone have any information with respect to OTF fonts in Node-Webkit?
Is this an expected deficit, a known issue, a bug, or something unrelated?  Any light shed on this issue would
be appreciated.

Thanks,

Jonathan (neologis)

Comment: Did you get this working, or is it still a problem?  Can you post code of an example that works in chrome but not node-wekbit?